# How do I get the Google Maps URL from an iPhone photo?

Tags: macos, iphone, iphoto, google-maps

I'm trying to find an easy way to get the URL (or pin) of a Google Map based on the GPS location attached to my iPhone images.

I see the map for my pictures in iPhoto, but I cannot find any way to see an URL for that map.

I found [this tool](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2012/01/locating-your-photos-on-google-maps/) but I cannot install it on my Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect your iPhone.

Open "Image Capture."

Import the picture if it's not already on your computer.

Open the Picture in "Preview." (Double clicking on the imported picture in "Preview" does this.)

Either go to Tools>Inspector or hit Cmd-I.

Click on the lowercase "i" in the Inspector window.

Click on GPS.

Clicking on "Locate" will give you a Google Maps link.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Photo Mapo iPhone app. It combines your photo with a google map and lets you share the result via Facebook, Twitter, Email. Produces a very nice aesthetically pleasing result. And, I think it is still FREE. Also, you can pick several styles, change the zoom level, adjust the map type.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photo-mapo/id525258687?mt=8#

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation if this product is made by you.